# External SSD causes "Accessory needs more power" when plugged into M1 iMac with external Thunderbolt monitor

Tags: ssd, thunderbolt, apple-silicon, thunderbolt-display

I have a new M1 iMac with **two Thunderbolt ports**.

I want to use one to control a small external monitor, and the other to run a very fast **external SSD**.

I was very disappointed to find that **when the monitor is plugged in**, I can't use the SSD. I get the warning:

> **Accessory needs more power**
> Disconnecting other accessories may allow this to work.

I suppose that this is a limitation of the M1 Macs, but it pretty much renders one of the Thunderbolt ports useless.

Is there any way to use both for what seems like a pretty normal use case (SSD + monitor)?

Answer (score 3):

#### Plug in the devices in a different order

In a [discussion in the MacRumors forums](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-much-power-can-the-thunderbolt-ports-provide.2342602/), Vogon Poetry says that power is attributed based on the order in which things are plugged in.

For me, this meant that plugging in my SSD *before* my external monitor allowed both to function, whereas plugging in the monitor first caused the **Accessory needs more power** error.

**[update]** Rebooting does not cause the SSD to be ejected (i.e. does not require re-establishing the plugging in order).

**[14 months later]** Since adopting the habit of plugging in my SSD first, I have not once had the error.

Comment: WHat happens when both are connected and you reboot? Will the order be correct here?

Comment: It works fine — I added it to the answer.

Comment: Surely the plugin order is re-established each reboot - nothing is saved to keep the order - unless you can point to documentation or files showing the order.

Comment: It worked for me, but I agree that it's probably not preserving the order. It seems more likely that booting with both devices plugged in is simply an alternative solution to the original problem. I'll have to do some testing to find out.